# Executing script by using function callproc from cx_Oracle module in python 2.7.5

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I'm relatively new to Python.
I'm currently working on SQL statement execution in Oracle DB.

When I execute query:

```
query = 'select * from table' 
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

everything is going fine, but when I try to execute script:

script in plain text:

```
begin
 SIEBEL_DBA.X_DR_DEPLOY(id => '1-4NANEI', env_code => 'SVE_SIT');
end;
/
```

code from script

```
script = "begin\nSIEBEL_DBA.X_DR_DEPLOY(id => '1-4NANEI', env_code => 'SVE_SIT');\nend;"
cursor.execute(script)

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get an exception, that this is not a query, but still this script has worked.

So from what I've googled, looks like I should use callproc function:

```
cursor.callproc['SIEBEL_DBA.X_DR_DEPLOY',{'id' : '1-4NANEI', 'env_code' : 'SVE_SIT'}]
connection.commit()

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

When I'm executing this statement, I'm also getting exception, but this time nothing has been changed in DB:

'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Could someone please point where I'm not correct and how should I modify statement so it would be working.

Huge thanks in advance!

RESOLUTION:

I was frustrated by the syntax and the complexity of callproc and callfunc functions.
I've found good resource: http://dbaportal.eu/sidekicks/sidekick-cx_oracle-code-paterns/#part1
in this link I found all needed info and examples on how to work with cx_Oracle library.

at the end I just needed to modify a bit my code:

```
cursor.callproc('SIEBEL_DBA.X_DR_DEPLOY', ['1-4NANEI', 'SVE_SIT'])
```

and the needed part was done, I didn't need to specify any return type, as script that I'm executing doesn't return any value, it just sets it.

Comment: I was frustrated by the syntax and the complexity of callproc and callfunc functions.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is because you are using `[ ]` where you should be using `()`:

```
cursor.callproc('SIEBEL_DBA.X_DR_DEPLOY',{'id' : '1-4NANEI', 'env_code' : 'SVE_SIT'})
```

Keep in mind the return type is required:

> Cursor.callfunc(name, returnType, parameters=[], keywordParameters =
>   {})
>
> Call a function with the given name. The return type is specified in
>   the same notation as is required by setinputsizes(). The sequence of
>   parameters must contain one entry for each argument that the function
>   expects. Any keyword parameters will be included after the positional
>   parameters. The result of the call is the return value of the
>   function.

Comment: Thanks for you're input, It cleared a bit my thoughts but not entirely! I've added resolution to my first post and also resource that I've read in order to fix it.